# Portable way to redirect funopen to stdin/stdout

Tags: c, android-ndk, stdio, bsd

I'm using [`funopen`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=funopen&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) (`fropen`, `fwopen` in particular) to emulate I/O interaction with user for testing purposes. So far it looks like this:

```c
FILE* F=fropen(...);
std::swap(F,stdin);
//  some code to test
std::swap(F,stdin);
fclose(F);
```

But according to standard it's an UB and it does not work on certain platforms (linux+clang+musl, android-ndk, probably some others) because it's not guaranteed for `stdin`/`stdout` to be an lvalue.

I've made a workaround for that problem, which swaps `FILE*` pointers if both are lvalues and `FILE` structs itself otherwise:

```c
void FSWP(FILE*& a, FILE*& b) {
    swap(a,b);
}
void FSWP(const FILE*a,const FILE*b) {
    swap(*const_cast<FILE*>(a), *const_cast<FILE*>(b));
}
```

This way it works on android-ndk, but still doesn't work on linux+clang+musl, and still is UB because `FILE` is implementation-defined and is not required to be moveable.

I've also tried `dup2`, but it works with descriptor numbers and `fileno()` returns `-1` for results of `funopen`.

Is there any portable way of doing this? Something like `freopen`, but accepting a `FILE*` pointer instead of `const char*` filename. Portability among *NIX systems is enough because `funopen` is not available on other platforms anyway.

Comment: In the first code snippet, do you mean `fopen`? Is the `fropen` a typo? And what is `funopen`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude [funopen](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=funopen&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports). In a nutshell, that's a function to create a `FILE*` pointer using a user-defined `read()` or `write()` function.

Comment: Added link to the post

Comment: It seems to be undefined behavior to access a dereferenced `FILE*` (See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)).

Comment: The `funopen` and `fropen` functions are BSD-specific function which means they are not portable to begin with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, my goal is to make it portable among different *nix systems relying on UB as little as possible. On linux I can use libbsd, on bsd and android it's native.

Comment: provided you don't have any other low-numbered, closed fd's, could use close()-then-dup() .. the FILE/stream stuff that sits on top of it and will likely not notice. The close()/dup() trick has been used so widely, and for decades, that it's likely universally supported.

Comment: sort of like x=dup(0), close(0), dup(your_fd) .. test .. close(0), dup(x), close(x)  if that makes any sense?

Comment: @AndrewAtrens I don't get what you mean. I can't use `dup` because there's no fd associated with `FILE*` generated by `funopen`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep. Sorry I wasn't clear. In stdio/unix each stream object (FILE *) sits on top of a unix file descriptor. 'stdin' for instance sits on top of unix fd 0.  You can use the 'int fileno(FILE *stream);' api to retrieve the unix fd for any given stream object.  What I'm proposing is to use close and dup on the raw unix fd's .. and don't mess with the stream objects at all. The stream objects reference the fd number and provide buffering and probably a few other things - if your program is single threaded it won't notice at all that the fd being referred to has been swizzled as I describe. :)

Comment: You mean, `dup` will give `fd=0` to me if I'd `fclose(0)` first? Nice hack indeed, but sadly not applicable to me because in-memory `FILE*` streams (`funopen`, `fmemopen`, `fopencookie`, etc.) does not have file descriptor associated with them.

Comment: yes correct, but it's close() not fclose() .. digging into libc I see that you are correct that funopen() and friends don't use the kernel system calls at all - and internally the fileno is set to -1 (I see now that you tried that with dup()) .. can you paste the exact error that you're seeing on linux+clang+musl?

Comment: @AndrewAtrens there's no error, it just does not work. I've made my own digging into musl source and found that `stdin/stdout/stderr` declared as const, and `FILE` struct declared as a 1-byte-long pointer target, so swapping it achieves nothing.

Comment: Ugh. Well I just cloned musl and I see FILE is defined as _IO_FILE which is defined in src/internal/stdio_impl.h - it's certainly bigger than one byte. Is the problem you are seeing in alltypes.h (that's a generated file)?

Comment: @AndrewAtrens there's two different definitions of `_IO_FILE`, one for internal, one for userspace. The one from `alltupes` is the userspace one. You can easily check it by `std::cout << sizeof(FILE)`

Comment: May I assume that you've considered the obvious .. using a third globally scoped FILE * for all your input and simply initializing it to stdin in main, then assigning to F and then test and then back to stdin?  Just seems too easy.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205978/discussion-between-denis-sheremet-and-andrew-atrens).

Comment: You cannot portably use `fropen` and friends to replace an open file. The only sane method is to dup2 it to a pipe controlled from another thread.

Comment: This is why **good code never hardcodes the standard streams** - code should take the stream it should do I/O on as an argument. Then your tests could just invoke that code with `F` instead of `stdout` as a parameter or whatever. Edit: obviously if you're doing some write-once code or a simple program which is meant to be a command-line pipe tool, then it's fine to hard-code the streams, and it's still "good" code. But *the moment you or any of your users want to test your code* is the moment when you already have a use-case for the reusability and flexibility of taking a custom I/O stream.

Comment: Even small programs which are meant as pipes generally have no great reason to hard-code the stream. It takes barely any typing to add a `FILE * input` or `FILE * output` parameter to each function that does I/O. In general, the strings `stdin` and `stdout` should only occur in high-level "business logic" parts of the code - everything else should receive them as more abstractly named parameters.

Comment: I realize **you** might not have the luxury of being able to fix whatever code you're having to test to follow this best practice - but I think it's important to use your question/problem as a good example for anyone else who comes along who *does* have  the opportunity to not put people like you in situations like this.